# Check if a translation exists for a field in DoctrineBehaviors

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-extensions

I have a problem with the `DoctrineBehaviors` bundle. I'm trying to get the translation for a specific language (French) for an entity that doesn't have the French translation. It returns the fallback language, that is OK for the frontend, but I need to know if that language have a translation, because I need to fill in my backend.

How can I know if a entity's field is translated to an specific language?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Translatable` entity, you can get all translations known to your specific entity ([documentation](http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/translatable.html#basic-examples)).

```
$product = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
    ->find($productId);

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Translation');
$translations = $repository->findTranslations($product);
```

The variable `$translations` now contains a keyed array, e.g.,

```
array(2) {
  ["en_US"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Keyboard"
  }
  ["fr_FR"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Clavier"
  }
}
```

Finding out if the entity is translated can is now simply checking whether the locale is in the array keys.

```
if (!array_key_exists('fr_FR', $translations)) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('product description not available in French');
}
```

Note that the `Translatable` entity does not contain the *default locale* (unless you have set `setPersistDefaultLocaleTranslation` to `true`).